# Can't login after suspend in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, suspend, login-screen

I have dual booted my system with Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I close the lid of my laptop and open it I can't login at all.

I can use mouse on login screen but can't type anything. Then I need to restart the system to login again.

I looked into many forums but nothing is working out. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Does Ubuntu respond to your mouse clicks?

Comment: @WhiteMars yes I can selelct options on login screen

Comment: Hi @008karan did you find the solution to this problem? I am dealing with a similar situation, and I will love to see an update on this question... how did you solve the issue? Thanks in advance.